# Distance from polygon to address using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, proximity, address

I have a layer that is polygons.
One of the data fields is a street address.

How can I determine which polygons are a street address that is more than X miles away from the polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up:

1. Exporting the parcel number and mailing address from the polygon feature to a table.
2. Geocoded the table to get points.
3. Renamed the Parcel Number field back to it's original (it was prefixed with User_)
4. Used the Near by Group toolbox (https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/finding-the-nearest-feature-with-the-same-attributes/) matching on the parcel number to add distance between the parcel polygon and the parcel's mailing address point.
5. Selected by attribute where distance was greater than XYZ distance.